# How do I change a command line variable's name in shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that converts an image's format and then do some image processing on it. The problem is that original command line arugument is abc.tiff. And after converting the format, I want to do something on abc.png. Is there a way to change the command line argument's name or extension?

Comment: do not change the argument, store it in a variable and change its value whenever you need.
pic=$1;

Comment: Then you can do `picpng=${pic%.tiff}.png`.